# How would I configure an EC2 instance To Download From MYSQL and Process The Data Based On A Script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, serverless

Coming from the serverless framework.

I can currently launch an EC2 instance from lambda.

I do not know how to then tell that EC2 instance to download all data for a user from MYSQL into memory, perform some row level operations and send the intermediate results to dynamodb or a persistent storage service.

Sub questions that I have:

Where would the script be stored, if it is a python script, then how would I let the EC2 get access to it upon launch?

Can I include in the script, an auto shutdown. So that once the task has completed then shut it down? If not then I can use dynamodb to keep track.

Comment: All of that can be done in user-data script. You didn't mention if you tried, so I assume you are not aware of it (sorry if the assumption is incorrect). More about scripting for Linux https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html and similar for Windows boxes. Obviously, if the problem is more specific to MySQL or processing data based on a script - you need to elaborate

Comment: yeah i should elaborate. I am aware of userData and I tried to pass a bash script through to it. I can do that in lambda, however, I think I am missing the connection between the bash script and the python script that I would like to run. I can get it into lambda, but I am not quite sure on how to make the bash script run the python file

Comment: You might also consider SSN Run Command. It allows you to run arbitrary scripts on EC2 remotely.

Comment: @jarmod do you mean ssh, or am I mistaken?

Comment: SSM Run command.  Typos are cruel

Comment: Yes, typo. Should read SSM Run Command. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html

Comment: @Vorsprung No worries, setting it up now